# get information of app in android

Tags: android

> hello expert,
>   i want to get information of all apk in mobile, like name,icon,date etc....
>   i refer [check it](http://www.androidsnippets.com/get-installed-applications-with-name-package-name-version-and-icon) but there are not satisfied solution. so can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your activity you should call

```
List<ApplicationInfo> applications = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
```

Then you can get the information by running though the applications list.

You can check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledApplications(int) for more info on the falgs you can use.

If you want the icon and install/update of an application you should instead use

```
List<PackageInfo> applications = getPackagerManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
```

This will give you a list of PackageInfos. Then you can acces the information you seek:

```
for(PackageInfo info : applications){
    Drawable icon = info.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getContext());
    long firstInstalled = info.firstInstallTime;
    long lastUpdate = info.lastUpdateTime;
}
```

Checkout http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html to see what else you can get from the packageinfo.

Comment: http://www.foksh.com/en/get-detailed-apk-app-information-for-android/
this kind of app information i want

Comment: can you tell me how can i get icon and date of app

Comment: I updated the answer, let me know if that is what you where looking for.

Comment: this thing i know and i try but "firstInstallTime" method are not supported.

Comment: i have try project in 9 API level and after they are supported.but 
in logcat i got 
firstInstallTim is :::::::1305907770197
so can you tell me what kind of value this is?

Comment: It is in Unix time: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time. Please remember to accept the answer if you feel it was the correct one.

Comment: no it is not. read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275784/packagemanager-issue-in-android

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answer,
You should also have a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html.

It holds various informations regarding the cellphone (or tablet)