# PackageManager issue in android

Tags: android

I can't get date in properManner, I use `PackageManager`:

***Code example***

```
::List<PackageInfo> applications = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
        for(PackageInfo info : applications){
          //  Drawable icon = info.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getBaseContext());
            long firstInstalled = info.firstInstallTime;
            long lastUpdate = info.lastUpdateTime;
            System.out.println("firstInstalled"+firstInstalled);
```

if I `print` firstInstalled to **LOGCAT** then I got result "firstInstalled is 1305907770197"
I can't able to understand what is this? can you help me?

Comment: 1305907770197 this is installed time in long you have to convert it to human readable date format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code

```
Date d = new Date(firstInstalled);
d.getDate();
d.getMonth();
d.getYear();
```

Comment: Agnihotri: It works, but the Android devs recommend using `Calendar` over `Date`, which is considered deprecated.

Comment: Ofcourse Calendar can be used its just matter of choice and I dont thinks its deprecated can you post a link to your recommendation

Comment: Agnihotri: See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html).

Comment: If you read closely you will find some of the constructor are deprecated not the whole class and the method I mentioned above is not deprecated yet :P and its just matter of choice I prfer date thats all

Comment: Agnihotri: Just part of the class, including the `getXXX` and `setXXX` methods.

Answer (score 2):

Look right there in your code. It says `long firstInstalled = info.firstInstallTime;`. It is a number representing the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

Maybe you want a more readable representation of that info?

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(firstInstalled);
```

Now you can extract and display the values for hour, day, year, etc. from the `cal` variable. See [`Calendar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) for further info.